# How to use iperf to measure the network parameters of a container（virtual firewall） between two containers in docker？

Tags: docker, networking, iperf3

I would like to ask how to use iperf to measure the network parameters of the container between the iperf-client and iperf-server container. I want to measure the network parameters of an intermediate container (e.g. vFW), but every time I generate traffic using iperf-client, the traffic is transferred directly from the iperf-client container to the iperf-server container and does not pass through the intermediate container. How can I solve this problem please?

I'm trying to do this using two defined networks but it's not working.Is there any way to solve this problem please?